# Django form validation error with incomplete fields but complete instance

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, modelform

I want to be able to do:

```
def update_profile(request, username):
    user = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)

    # update subset of profile, eg value_to_company is set in request.POST
    # but user (or an arbitrary number of other attributes) is not
    profile = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user)

    if not profile.is_valid():
        print profile.errors  #user is required
```

The problem that I have with this is that user definitely exists and is part of the instance, and I can't find anything in the docs to suggest that instance data wouldn't get into the bound data. But I also can't find anything that explicitly says that it *will*.

(The rest of this is justification for why I'm doing things the way I am, and ideas for solutions, you probably don't need to read it.)

If you want to know why I'm going through a form--not essential to the question--it's because I've got something like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User)
    value_to_company = models.IntegerField()

class ValueField(forms.Field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        vals = {'high': 0,
                'mid': 1}
        return vals[value]

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    value_to_company = ValueField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

That is, I'm doing type api-to-internal-representation-coercion in my forms already and I'd like to continue using that.

I could reimplement the forms.is_valid() loop, just checking for the fields on the form that already exist, something hacky like:

```
# replaces `if not profile.is_valid()` above:
errors = []
for field in request.POST.iterkeys():
    if field in profile.fields:
        profile.fields[field].to_python()
        if not profile.fields['field'].clean():
            errors.append #something
```

(I haven't actually looked at the logic internal logic, so I know that's wrong, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely just need to add `exclude = ('user',)` to your form. The forms instance mostly determines initial values, if your form includes the user field, but that field is posted with a blank value it *will* try to blank out the user field, resulting in the error.

Comment: At first I thought that works, but the problem is that it seems to reset _all_ fields that aren't included in the `POST`. I just want to update a model, changing things that are included.

Comment: Well `user` should be excluded one way or another. You don't want users associating their profile with a different user. But, in general, you must provide an actual HTML field for every field in the model that's not excluded. With an instance, they'll all be prepopulated with the currently set value. If there is no field in the HTML form or the user explicitly sets the value to empty, then it will unset the field.

Comment: You're right about the user, I was mostly just trying to demonstrate that my models have a foreign key with a common example. But I guess what you're saying is that there's no clean way to update a model using forms, unless you include everything? I'm not actually displaying any forms in this instance, I'm trying to re-use their validation in my api, and I wanted to let people update with just the fields they want to change.

Comment: Not quite. You just need to limit the form to what you need. If there's certain fields that won't ever be updated in this manner, then add those to `exclude`. But, yes, you must post all the information for all the fields that are not excluded, even if that information is unchanged.

Comment: I have also hopped so. I am also using forms for validation of RESTful API and have the same problem. I want to support fields updating. Those fields which are required shouldn't be unset anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://groups.google.com/group/django-piston/browse_thread/thread/1ca2fd1c89f3df4e) in [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/4fe8af1db59d/piston/forms.py).

It adds additional form method `merge_from_initial` which you call before you call `is_valid` and it populates the missing fields from the object given.

I have changed it a bit and am using:

```
class BaseModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Subclass of `forms.ModelForm` which makes sure that the instance values are present in the form
    data, so you don't have to send all old values for the form to actually validate. Django does not
    do this on its own.
    """

    def merge_from_instance(self):
        # Internals
        self.data._mutable = True

        fun = lambda v: v not in self.data.keys()
        for field in filter(fun, self.fields.keys()):
            if field not in self.initial:
                continue
            value = self.initial.get(field)
            if isinstance(self.instance._meta.get_field(field), related.ManyToManyField):
                self.data.setlist(field, value)
            else:
                self.data[field] = value
```